# Is there a way to debug a function when rendering an Rmarkdown document?

Tags: r, debugging, r-markdown, knitr, rdebug

I am trying

```r
debug(myFunction)
```

and

```r
res <- rmarkdown::render("file_using_myFunction.Rmd", output_format = "all", envir = new.env())
```

It enters the browser, but when I try to evaluate anything inside the browser, there is no output:

[image]

Is there some way to get debugging browser to work with `rmarkdown::render`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output has been redirected internally, so you won't see any output in the R console. To stop the redirect, you can first call `sink()`.